# Disabling ultraWebGrid

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I have an infragistics ultraWebGrid working as a selection list in a web form in asp.net. When user makes a row selection I want to make the grid disabled or lock the active row (to selection row) until the user ends up with a process flow

I found the code below as a solution

Client-Side

```
function DisableGrid()
{
   var grid = igtbl_getGridById("UltraWebGrid1");
   grid.Element.disabled=true;
}
```

Server-side:

```
UltraWebGrid1.DisplayLayout.AllowUpdateDefault = 
   Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.AllowUpdate.No
```

The javascript function seems to do what exactly I want to but the grid is reseted after a postback.On the other side the server side code doesnt seem to do what I want.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the BeforeRowDeactivate client side event handler to prevent moving to another row.  There is an example of this in the Infragistics forums [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/47266/303512.aspx#303512).  You can find more information on the client side events in the documentation: [WebGrid Client-Side Events](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2011.1/CLR4.0/?page=WebGrid_Client_Side_Events_CSOM.html).